# Trying to learn about kernel PCA but cannot understand some math.

Tags: linear-algebra, education, computational-mathematics

I'm trying to learn about kernel PCA by reading through the paper of it's creators (I assume) ["Nonlinear Component Analysis as a Kernel Eigenvalue Problem", Bernhard Schölkopf, Alexander Smola, Klaus-Robert Müller, Technical Report No 44, 1996](http://www.face-rec.org/algorithms/Kernel/kernelPCA_scholkopf.pdf)

I don't understand the part where (page 3 of the above pdf) if you combine the equations (7) and (8) you get the (9), that is:
if
$$\lambda (\Phi(x_k)\cdot \mathbf V)=(\Phi(x_k)\cdot \bar C\mathbf V)\; \text{for all $k=1,\ldots, M $}$$
and
$$ \mathbf V = \sum_{i=1}^M a_i\Phi(x_i) $$
we get
$$ \lambda \sum_{i=1}^M a_i(\Phi(x_k)\cdot \Phi(x_i)) = \frac 1 M \sum_{i=1}^M a_i(\Phi(x_k)\cdot \sum_{j=1}^M \Phi(x_j))(\Phi(x_j) \cdot \Phi(x_i)) $$

using the covariance matrix $\bar C$ in the *feature space* for our $M$ centered observations:
$$ \bar C = \frac 1 M \sum_{j=1}^M \Phi(x_j) \Phi(x_j)^\mathsf T $$

What happened to the transposed $\Phi(x_j)^\mathsf T$ inside the sum in the covariance matrix?

Comment: Is $\Phi(x_j)$ a row vector or a column vector?

Comment: @HowDoIMath Since $x_j$ is a vector of observation parameters $x_j \in \mathbb R^N$, so $\Phi(x_j)$ is an arbitrary high dimensionality transformation, possibly of infinite dimensions, $\Phi : \mathbb R^N \to \mathbb R^d \;, d>>N$

Comment: I believe that $\Phi(x_j)\Phi(x_j)^T$ has simply been replaced by the dot product $\Phi(x_j)\cdot\Phi(x_j)$. Will this make sense?